# optimizing apache and mysql for android clients requests

Tags: android, mysql, apache, http

I would like to know which apache/httpd parameters a relevant to set, if I expect a high number of connections from different IPs, getting same ammount of data in the same time. As example: I would have 10000 mobile devices that try to get data from server in the same time. The dataset is about 100k big and is generated by a php script. Each call make a query to the database. How apache(and mysql) should be configured to stay alive during this requests?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die('Could not connect' );
mysql_select_db('mydb', $con) or die('Could not select database.');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results");
mysql_close($con); 
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $items[] = array(
     's' => $row['sport'],
    ....
 );
 echo json_encode($items);
}
```

Regards!
Dimitri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use mysqli API and not mysql (https://www.php.net/mysqli).

Then you MUST use the bind param technique (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) beacuse the generated query have so much better performance because mysql deosn't have to rebuild the eexecution plan of the query but only reexecute it.

Server side pay attention to doesn't slow MyISAM driver but InnoDB. If you can manage the table structure adopt well known normalization practice : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

Also do the code inside your while in async way so u can "parallelize" the execution of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would take in look in all this topics. Do I need to do something at apache side to allow many parallel connections? Regards

Comment: about "bind param technique". My query is line "SELECT * FROM results WHERE version = {$_GET["version"]}". So the use pass always a version by a query.. is it also possible to use bind param here?

Comment: Yes you can, and is better also if the query is simple

Comment: At server side the connection pool is automatically managed by php+apache. if u want some customization look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php

Comment: because the query is simple and depends only on "version". Does it has sense to pre-save data to files? for example: v1.txt, v2.txt etc... where "v1" is a actually a "version" of data. Then the script, called by the user (getdata.php) read the file and gives output back to user.. Then it would be no requests to mysql at all... would it increase the speed and availability?

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understand what you mean, but access to file is slower than access to database apart from really strange situation. And also using db without unnecessary optimization improve code quality .